# After successful open(), program is stalling on read()

Tags: c, io, low-level-io

I've been banging my head against my desk for a few hours now, trying to figure out why the following code is stalling at `while(chars = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SZ)) > 0)`. The `printf` on the line directly following is not being called and the one directly above is. The file descriptor is returning `0`, a valid value.

```
char *infile = argv[1];
int fd,chars;

if ((fd = open(infile, O_RDONLY) < 0)) {
    perror("open()");
    exit(1);
}
printf("%s - opened (fp: %d)\n", infile, fd);
while((chars = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SZ)) > 0){
    printf("%d\n", chars);
    for(i = 0; i < chars; i++){
        c = buff[i];
        total++;
        count[c]++;
    }
}
```

I don't even know how to debug this since nothing is being triggered following the line in question and everything looks fine before this line.

The full, compilable code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <unistd.h>

#define BUFF_SZ 4096

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        if(argc != 2)
                perror("Wrong number of arguments!");

        int fd;
        char *infile = argv[1];
        char buff[BUFF_SZ];
        int chars,c,c2,i;
        long long total = 0;
        long long count[256];
        char line[71];

        printf("zeroing count[]\n");
        for (c = 0; c < 256; c++) {
                count[c] = 0;
        }

        if ((fd = open(infile, O_RDONLY) < 0)) {
                perror("open()");
                exit(1);
        }
        printf("%s - opened (fp: %d)\n", infile, fd);
        while((chars = read(fd, buff, BUFF_SZ)) > 0){
                printf("%d\n", chars);
                for(i = 0; i < chars; i++){
                        c = buff[i];
                        total++;
                        count[c]++;
                }
        }
        close(fd);
        printf("%s closed\n", infile);

        if(chars < 0){
                perror("read()");
        }

        printf("outputting results\n");
        for (c = 0;c < 256; c++) {
                printf("\t%d of 256\n", c+1);
                snprintf(line, 70, "%.70lf\n",
                         ((float)count[c] / (float)total));
                for (c2 = 68; c2; c2--) {
                        if (line[c2] != '0'
                                && line[c2] != '.')
                                break;
                }
                line[++c2] = 0;
                printf("%s\n", line);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens if, when the program hangs, you type a few words at it, then press RETURN, then control-D, then RETURN again?  Also, please post a complete program that can be compiled and run.

Comment: It does what it's supposed to do with the infile. That makes sense... `stdin` in is zero. It's supposed to be reading from an infile on the commandline though... I'll post the full code now.

Comment: It was evident from the title alone that it was reading from a terminal (or maybe some other device, or a pipe).

Comment: In retrospect, yes, @JimBalter. What does that add to this thread though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your assignment to `fd`.

```
if ((fd = open(infile, O_RDONLY) < 0)) {
```

should be:

```
if ((fd = open(infile, O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
```

The clue was when you said that `fd` is 0. That was unlikely, since fd 0 is stdin, and this shouldn't happen unless you closed stdin before opening infile.

You were assigning `fd` the result of comparing the return value of `open` with 0, instead of assigning the return value itself.

Comment: Ugh! I can't believe I missed that. Was driving me insane. Thanks!

Comment: Don't beat yourself up. You aren't even close to the first, won't be the last; it's up there with using = when you mean ==, which I've done myself in the past week or so. But did you try linting it before posting?

Comment: This is the third instance of a variant of this bug posted to [c] today. People should use good compilers and appropriate warning levels. They should also read the code they write ... when would (( expression )) ever be necessary?

Comment: Good coding standard is also required to avoid such mistakes

Answer (score 1):

You only need to rearrange the parenthesis

```
if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) < 0) {
```